# why this javscript code giving undefined as a result? (Calculating GCD), I don't know why it's not entering if block

Tags: javascript, greatest-common-divisor

I don't know why its not entering if block.Maybe because of type coercion. Please correct me and tell me what's the mistake in this code.

```js
function calculateGCD(a, b) {
  if (b === 0) {
    return a;
  } else
    console.log(a, b);
  a > b ? calculateGCD(b, (a % b)) : calculateGCD(a, (b % a));
}

function main() {
  let n1, n2, gcd;
  n1 = +prompt("enter 1st number?");
  n2 = +prompt("enter second number?");

  gcd = calculateGCD(n1, n2);

  document.write(gcd);
}


main();
```

Comment: because you are not returning any value from your recursive call ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function you should return the result.

```
    function calculateGCD(a, b) {
      let result
      if (b === 0) {
        return a;
      } else {
       console.log(a, b);
       a > b ? result = (b, (a % b)) : result = (a, (b % a));
    }
   return result
  }
```

Comment: `a > b ? result = (b, (a % b)) : result = (a, (b % a));` is quite a strange syntax. first of all, what would the result of `(b, (a%b))` be? Ie you forgot to add the name of the function. And second. The more readable variant would be `result = a > b ? calculateGCD(b, a%b) : calculateGCD(a, b%a)`

Comment: thanks for your feedback, the syntax is from the author of the post and I don't want to complicate things for him, I just add correction so the code works fine to complete his project and slowly he will grasp the concepts and the best practices.

Comment: Thanks , I forgot that I also have to return the value . It was working in c++ though.